# How would I view console log of this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, console.log

I'm trying to fix an issue as stated in a previous stack overflow but I'm not getting any replies, so I'm trying to figure it out myself anyway...

How would I view console data from this code, so I can see exactly what heights are being calculated?

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
   var offset = window.pageYOffset;
   var wheight = window.innerHeight;
   var html = document.documentElement;
   var docheight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,
   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
   var progress = offset / wheight;

   document.getElementById("SVGID_1_").setAttribute("y1", 93000 + progress * 93000);
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/11x3cwnr/

Comment: There is nothing being logged to the console?

Answer (score 0):

Typing console.info(some_variable) and viewing in the console of your browser. usually typing F12

Answer (score 0):

Just add `console.log` lines to your javascript like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/11x3cwnr/4/

View the console output (in most browsers) by hitting F12.

Answer (score 0):

Update the code with console.log statements, like below:

```
window.onscroll = function (event) {
   var offset = window.pageYOffset;
   var wheight = window.innerHeight;
   var html = document.documentElement;
   var docheight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,
   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
   var progress = offset / wheight;
   // HERE'S THE LOG STATEMENT
   console.log("Progress = " + progress);
   document.getElementById("SVGID_1_").setAttribute("y1", 93000 + progress * 93000);
}
```

Then use Chrome or Firefox and right click on the image of the face in your example, inspect element, and then pick the Console tab.  Or, in Chrome, at least, just hit F12 to get directly to the console.  Now when you scroll the face image, you will see what the value of progress is.